# jquery make div with image get smaller

Tags: javascript, jquery, fadeout

Hey guys i got an image inside a div and iam moving it down at a specific time by giving it a delay. I was just wondering when it is moving down how do i make it become smaller as it goes down the screen till eventually it disappears completely at a specfic location i gave it.

So far this code makes it move down with a delay function on it and a duration.

```
$('#fourth').animate({
    width: '100px',
    height: '100px'
}, 3000, function() {
    $(this).show('fast').animate({
        top : '-=-100'
    }, 
    {duration: 2000}
)
```

Thanks for all the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the width and height to the `animate`.

```
$(this).show('fast').animate({
    top : '-=-100',
    width: 0,
    height: 0
}, 
{duration: 2000})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xMV5Q/1/

Also, `-=-` is the same as `+=` which is a bit more understandable.

Comment: but will this get smaller as it gose down ?

Comment: Yes; it's animating to a width and height of `0`. Assuming it starts with a width and height greater than `0` it *has* to get smaller.

Comment: @AliBOOM The div will get smaller, the image itself however will not get smaller. If you were using an img tag, the image would also get smaller.